# Arithmetical representation $F(x,y,z)\Longleftrightarrow (x+z)=y \lor (y+z)=x$

Tags: arithmetic

I am kind of confused which function $f:\mathbb{N}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$
is presented by $F(x,y,z)\Longleftrightarrow (x+z)=y \lor (y+z)=x$

I know that $f(x,y)=y-x$ is represented by $F(x,y,z)\Longleftrightarrow (x+z=y)\lor ((z=0)\land \exists w(x+w)=y)$

But the or symbol confuses me ... My guess was
$f(x,y)=max\{x-y,y-x\}$ but i think this is wrong due to a missing check in F(x,y,z)

For info:
An function $f:N^k⟶N$ is arithmeic representable when there is a arithmetic formula F with $F(x_1,...,x_k,m)⟺f(x_1,...,x_k)=m$

Comment: I don't quite get the context of your question. Are you dealing with [Integer Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)?

Comment: An function $f:\mathbb{N}^k\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is arithmeic representable when there is a arithmetic formula F with $F(x_1,...,x_k,m)\Longleftrightarrow f(x_1,...,x_k)=m$

So i got my Formula F here and i want to find the function f for it

Comment: Try $f(x,y)=|x-y|$

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give us more context about this question and give us all necessary background in the question. I'm not clear on the relationship between $f$ vs $F$, or on what exactly you mean by "arithmetical representation", or what operations you do and don't allow to appear on the right-hand side of the definition of $F$.  You say the "or symbol confuses you" but I'm not sure how to help you.  You can read the definition of $\lor$ in many standard textbooks.  Do you have a specific question?